# jQuery Toggle Animation to work only on selected class

Tags: jquery, lightning-aura-components

I am having trouble using the jQuery Toggle effect to show only the selected one's details. I have a view that consists of all Case Owners tabs. And under cases owners are the dropdowns of their detailed case info. I tried to use $('caseInfo').slideToggle(500) to create the toggle effect. However, doing this causes all Case Owners tabs to show everything at once. Any ideas how I can modify it to show only the Case Owner's detail that I click on?

Aura component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute type="Case[]" name="cases"/>
    <aura:attribute type="User" name="caseOwner"/>
    <!-- <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.printList}" /> -->


<div id="caseClass">        
        <div><h3 class="caseOwner" onclick="{!c.toggle}">User Name: {!v.caseOwner.Name}</h3></div>

        <aura:iteration var="currentCase" items="{!v.cases}">
        <ul class="caseInfo">
            <li class="list">Case Number: {!currentCase.CaseNumber}</li>
            <li class="list">Status: {!currentCase.Status}</li>
            <li class="list">Subject: {!currentCase.Subject}</li>
            <li class="list">Divison: {!currentCase.Division__c}</li>
        </ul>
    </aura:iteration>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

> toggle: function(component, event, helper){
>
> > $('.caseInfo').slideToggle(300);
> >         }
> >     })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution after trying various ways to make it worked!

in the div, I added `onclick="{!c.toggleSwitch}"` and below is the function that makes the jQuery Toggle Animation to work only on selected class

```
toggleSwitch : function(component, event, helper){
    var target;
    if (event.getSource) {
        //handling a framework component event
        target = event.getSource(); // this is Component object
    } else {
        //handling a native browser event
        target = event.target.value;
        $(event.target.parentElement).find(".selectedClass").toggle(400);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in a lightning-specific way, but you should be able to use `event.currentTarget` instead of the selector `$('.caseInfo')`.